# Making a navigation bar centred

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm trying to make my nav bar look similar to the nav bar on this website. (http://thestyleinsider.weebly.com/)
I have two problems in relation to that. I can't centre the links (to the right) even though I have used `"text-align: centre-right;"` in the css. I'm also wondering how I can bring the links into the middle of the nav bar (so they're not stuck to the top of the webpage). I have tried adjusting the `padding` but nothing works. Any help is much appreciated!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPxdyN

Comment: "center to the right" and "text-align: centre-right;" O.o Those two words kinda are contradicting each other don't ya think?

Comment: I read somewhere that centre-right exists. My head is absolutely fried. I changed it to just right and it's still the same

Comment: Try this for an [excellent reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) on this and other css/js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible answer is this. Set the text to be aligned to the right side and a line height enough to reach the middle of the navigation bar.

```
nav {
  line-height:80px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so so so so much!! I have searched and searched for a solution for this for days, so I am so grateful for this. Do you know how I could add a small image (logo) to the other side of the navbar (which can be clicked through to get back to the home page)? I tried inserting another <a> to the nav bar list but put it in it's own div so it could be styled differently, but it just forced the rest of the list down to a new line. Again, any help is appreciated!

Comment: check @Dennis Jamin answer but instead of `margin-left:auto` use `margin-right:auto` to move to the right just the first element.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to align the text? This is exactly what flexbox was invented for.

```
nav {
    display: flex;
}

nav a:first-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Check out this [working codepen example](http://codepen.io/DennisJamin/pen/meQzOO).

Applying display: flex to the nav container changes the behaviour of it's children and turns them into flex items. This in turn [changes the behaviour of margin-left](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#box-model). Setting `margin-left` of the first nav child to auto now makes sure the entire space on the left side of the flex items is filled and moves them all to the right.

**update**

I have updated my answer to also take into account that you would like to display on the left. By using flexbox you can add the logo as last child to the nav container, still being able to use `:first-child`. By changing the order of the last child (which contains the logo and which has a `.logo` class) you can switch it to the first position. This does not however make it `:first-child` and thus does not get `margin-left` applied.

```
nav {
    display: flex;
}

nav a {
    order: 2;
}

nav a.logo {
    order: 1;
}

nav a:first-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Check out this [updated codepen example](http://codepen.io/DennisJamin/pen/meQzbP)

**update 2**

As Henri Vonfire [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651941/making-a-navigation-bar-centred/33652432#comment55078250_33652044) you could also use the logo as a first-child and use `margin-right` to let flex fill up the space between the first and second flex item. This makes it possible to drop the changing of order  entirely.

```
nav {
    display: flex;
}

nav a:first-child {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Check out this [last codepen example](http://codepen.io/DennisJamin/pen/MazPJP)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know text-align does not work well with multiple properties. Here is what I would do.

1) Take the height off of your main-nav class.

3) Set text-align:right, and give it some padding. This padding with give the main nav it's height and center the links vertically.

```css
.main {position: relative;}
    .main-nav {
      background-color: black;
      z-index: 150;
      text-align:right;
      padding:20px;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      top:0;}
    .main-nav-scrolled {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      background: yellow;}
    a:link, a:visited {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center-left;
      padding: 8px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      height: 80px;
      border-bottom: 18px;
      border-top: 18px;}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #ffbc00;
}
a img {
  border: 0;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <a href="index3.html">Home</a>
  <a</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="directory.html">Directory</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!